# Android xml graphical layout/design not loaded properly of existing project

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to import an existing android project, project xml graphical/design layout is not loaded . I made a new test project and the  xml graphical layout working fine, I dont know what is the problem.I just installed new android sdk r14, I dont knw what is the problem, Can anyone help me in this regard?
You can see it in the snapshot attached.
Thank you 
!![image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy fix:

`Right click on the layout file` -> `Open With` -> `Android Layout Editor`

**Updated answer**

In Eclipse, go to `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations` and select `*.xml` and then press `Default` on the `Android Layout Editor` entry in the list of associated editors.

Comment: yes I know this solution but I have to always do this manually :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this matches your exact issue, but I have seen other people with issues after the updating to r14.

Here is a link that might point you in the right direction.
http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/fix-the-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-adt-14

good luck.